# Writing python function to extract matching rows from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,5,5,5], 'B' : [4,2,1, 1], 'C' : [2,2,7,1]})
```

I want to get those rows in df1 based on foll. condition:

```
df1.loc[(df1['A'] == 5) & (df1['B'] == 4) & (df1['C'] == 2)]
```

How can I make it more generic i.e. I want to have a function, where I specify both the column names and the values I am looking for as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).  For the conditions in your question, this would involve constructing a string along the lines of `'A==5 & B==4 & C==2'`.

To setup the problem, I'm going to assume you provide a list of tuples, in the form of `(column, comparison, value)` as your conditions, for example `('A', '==', 5)`.

Then you could write a function along the lines of:

```
def extract_matching_rows(df, conditions):
    conditions = ' & '.join(['{}{}{}'.format(*c) for c in conditions])
    return df.query(conditions)
```

If you only care about equality comparisons, you could just hard code in the `'=='` and eliminate it from your condition tuples.

Example usage with slightly different conditions:

```
conditions = [('A', '>=', 5), ('B', '==', 4), ('C', '<', 3)]
extract_matching_rows(df1, conditions)

   A  B  C
0  5  4  2
```

Note that you can even compare columns with `query`:

```
conditions = [('B', '>=', 'C'), ('A', '==', 5)]
extract_matching_rows(df1, conditions)

   A  B  C
0  5  4  2
1  5  2  2
3  5  1  1
```

Comment: thanks @root, does your solution work if instead of number, there is a string comparison?

Comment: Yes, but not in a very straightforward way. The query string needs to have quotes within it: `'A=="yes" & B==4'`.  In order to get this, you'll need quotes in your string, i.e. double quotes within the single quotes defining your string, or vice versa:  `('A', '==', '"yes"')`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could implement a check within your function to determine if you're comparing with a string, and then format your query slightly differently if so: `'{}{}"{}"'.format(*c)`.

Answer (score 2):

Assign what you are looking for to a series

```
# first row of df1
looking_for = df1.iloc[0, :]
```

Then evaluate the equality and find where all are equal in a row.

```
df1.eq(looking_for).all(1)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Use this as a filter

```
df1[df1.eq(looking_for).all(1)]
```

[image]

Generically, assign any series

```
looking_for = pd.Series([1, 5, 7], list('BAC'))

df1[df1.eq(looking_for).all(1)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this,filterdf is your function :

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,5,5,5], 'B' : [4,2,1,1], 'C' : [2,2,7,1]})

def filterdf(df,col1,col2,val1,val2):
    return df[(df[col1] == val1) & (df[col2] == val2)]

df2 = filterdf(df1,'A','B',5,4)
print(df2)
Out:
   A  B  C
0  5  4  2
```

Comment: Please let me know what is the issue before downvoting!!

Comment: @GuaravDhama I can't see an issue.  That down vote was un warranted in my opinion.  +1 from me.